# In ASP.NET MVC 5 view, jQuery weird post method error 404 wrong URL hit issue

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc-5

I am having a weird issue with ajax post request URL in ASP.NET MVC 5 from Razor view page.

My controller is:

```
[Authorize]
public class DashboardController : Controller
{
    [HttpPost]
    public JsonResult LoadSendAlertPage(bool param1, bool param2)
    {
        // do some work
        return Json("ok");
    }
}
```

Jquery1:

```
$.post("LoadSendAlertPage", { param1: _param1, param2: _param2}, function (result) {
                console.log(result);
            });
```

Jquery2:

```
$.post("Dashboard/LoadSendAlertPage", { param1: _param1, param2: _param2}, function (result) {
                console.log(result);
            });
```

Jquery3:

```
$.post("/LoadSendAlertPage", { param1: _param1, param2: _param2}, function (result) {
                console.log(result);
            });
```

So here is the problem: See jquery1,2,3 sometime 1 successfully hits the `LoadSendAlertPage()` and randomly then doesn't works. Sometime 2,3 works other not. In browser console I saw its trying to hit wrong URL when this not working. See the [image: picture of wrong URL].

Anyone having this experience? Please share idea how come one works sometime another not randomly. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Keep jquery 1 if it works. I recomended change name of the methods for somethings simple. Maybe it will help.

Comment: @Madbeap Ofcourse I kept jQuery always one but for sometime it was feeling me that randomly same jQuery not working & finally found why, answered bellow.